# Web Deploy API and Web Management Service (WMSVC)

Tags: api, msdeploy

I'm trying to translate the following WORKING command line into web deploy api (Microsoft.Web.Deployment) code:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:contentPath="\\myserver\code_to_deploy" -dest:contentPath="Default Web Site",wmsvc="mysandbox",userName="MyWebDeployUser",password="MyPassword" -allowUntrusted
```

My looks like this:

```
string srcPath = "\\myserver\code_to_deploy";
string destPath = "Default Web Site";

DeploymentBaseOptions sourceOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions();
sourceOptions.TraceLevel = TraceLevel.Verbose;          
sourceOptions.Trace += new EventHandler<DeploymentTraceEventArgs>(Src_Trace);

DeploymentBaseOptions destOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions();            
destOptions.UserName = "MyWebDeployUser";
destOptions.Password = "MyPassword";
destOptions.AddDefaultProviderSetting("contentPath", "wmsvc", "mysandbox");         
destOptions.AuthenticationType = "basic";

destOptions.TraceLevel = TraceLevel.Verbose;
destOptions.Trace += new EventHandler<DeploymentTraceEventArgs>(Dest_Trace);

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, chain, err) =>
{
    return true;
};          
DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions = new DeploymentSyncOptions();
syncOptions.DeleteDestination = true;

using (DeploymentObject depObj = DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.ContentPath, srcPath, sourceOptions))
{               
    var summary = depObj.SyncTo(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.IisApp, destPath, destOptions, syncOptions);
}
```

When the code makes the call to 'AddDefaultProviderSetting' it fails saying that wmsvc is not supported by the provider. If I remove the line I receive a 401 from the server. Any examples of doing this or other help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have found a solution but here is a code snippet that allows to use wmsvc for those who need it:

```
        DeploymentBaseOptions destinationOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions()
        {
            UserName = "<user_name>",
            Password = "<password>",
            IncludeAcls = false,
            AuthenticationType = "Basic",
            UseDelegation = true,
            ComputerName = "https://<server>:8172/msdeploy.axd?Site=<website>"
        };

       // Use -allowUntrusted option
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
                (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; });

       string package = <zip_package_fullPath>;
       string parameters = <project_SetParameters_xml_fullPath>;
       using (var deploymentObject = DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.Package, package))
        {
            deploymentObject.SyncParameters.Load(parameters);
            DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions = new DeploymentSyncOptions();

            DeploymentChangeSummary results = deploymentObject.SyncTo(destinationOptions, syncOptions);
        }
```

It's quite hard to find documentation on these topics. Btw, I've not succeeded in using AddDefaultProviderSetting, even by creating a .exe.configSettings file and I'm not sure it's the right method to achieve what you want to.

To create a virtual application instead of a website, only .SetParameters.xml has to be changed from

```
<setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="<WebSite>" />
```

to

```
<setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="<WebSite>/<VirtualApp>" />
```

Hope this helps.